# Excel - Every combination of column a and column b into column d and e

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not really sure how to even ask this question. So I took a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

I'd like to output every combination of columns a and b into column d and e. I've seen many examples of how to combine a and b into one column, but I need them into separate columns.

I'm sure this is possible, I just don't know what to even search for to start

Comment: This would be called a Cartesian product or cross-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two formula.

Put this in D1 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/COUNTA(B:B))+1),"")
```

Put this in E1 and copy down:

```
=IF(D1<>"",INDEX($B$1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),COUNTA(B:B))+1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with unequal number of rows in columns A and B?

Comment: @davidmneedham it does now

Comment: @ScottCraner Can it spill?  I have a list of dates and processes which may change, but looking for a formula based cartesian product that will extend if the number of dates or processes changes.   I'll create a new question referencing this one with what I've been trying unless you jump in with a "it does now" :)

Answer (score 1):

use Microsoft's [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) *power tools* for making a cartesian product of two variables (or table), if you use Excel 2016.
(For Excel 2010-2013, use the free MS add-in [Power Query for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379).)

Similar to the way described [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/05/11/cartesian-product-joins-for-the-excel-person/), you can

- import both columns as separated table in Power Query (Excel 2016: ribbon Data > From Table)
- then add an helper column with the same value (e.g. 1),
- merge both table
- keep the original imported column

You could theoretically make a cartesian product not only from two column but also from two tables of several columns.

Here the M-Code of both table:

*Table2*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "CrossColumn", each 1)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

*Table 1*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "CrossColumn", each 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom",{"CrossColumn"},Table2,{"CrossColumn"},"Table2",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded {0}",{"CrossColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```