# Add a blank with FilterXML

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've reworded this question as had no response from the first... maybe it was a bit wordy.

My original data is below.
Note - this is just test data, in my file it's a spilled range created from a formula (see [Formula to create a cartesian product from two data sets in a spilled range](https://superuser.com/questions/1671787/formula-to-create-a-cartesian-product-from-two-data-sets-in-a-spilled-range) for that formula)

| Date | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 29/08/2021 | A |
| 29/08/2021 | B |
| 29/08/2021 | C |
| 30/08/2021 | A |
| 30/08/2021 | B |
| 30/08/2021 | C |

I add XML tags to the data using these formula (note:  the `!null!` part is where my problem is):
**Date**:  `="<a>" & IF($B$4:$B$9=OFFSET($B$4:$B$9,-1,0),"!null!",$B$4:$B$9) & "</a>"`
**Text**:  `="<b>" & $D$4:$D$9 & "</b>"`

[image]

And then `FILTERXML` to turn the results into a two column spill range.

```
=LET(xml,"<y><x>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,D3#,E3#) & "</x></y>",
     x,"//x/a",
     y,"//x/b",
     CHOOSE({1,2},FILTERXML(xml,x),FILTERXML(xml,y)))
```

[image]

How do I change the `!null!` place markers for actual empty cells?
`""`, `"&#0;"`, `"<a></a>"` and anything else I've tried returns `#VALUE!` errors.

### Answer:

The answer given by @HasanNahiyanNobel gave me the idea to use `SUBSTITUTE`.  On its own it causes the dates to appear as their numerical value and formatting the cells doesn't affect that.  Using `TEXT` formatting around the `FILTERXML` that supplies the dates sorted that problem.

My final formula is:

```
=LET(xml,"<y><x>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,Z4#,AA4#) & "</x></y>",
           x,"//x/a",
           y,"//x/b",
           CHOOSE({1,2},TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML(xml,x),"!null!",""),"dd-mmm"),FILTERXML(xml,y)))
```

Comment: What about wrap your formula into a substitute function? `SUBSTITUTE(LET(...), "!null!", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is not *really* large, you can simply use an if-condition in `G3` like this:

```
=IF(LET(xml,"<y><x>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,D3#,E3#) & "</x></y>",
        x,"//x/a",
        y,"//x/b",
        CHOOSE({1,2},FILTERXML(xml,x),FILTERXML(xml,y)))="!null!",
    "",
    LET(xml,"<y><x>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,D3#,E3#) & "</x></y>",
        x,"//x/a",
        y,"//x/b",
        CHOOSE({1,2},FILTERXML(xml,x),FILTERXML(xml,y)))
)
```

However, this has to go through the same `LET` function twice. If you need to avoid this, you can use columns `I` and `J`, where:

| Cell | Function |
| --- | --- |
| `I3` | `=IF(G3:G8="!null!", "", G3:G8)` |
| `J3` | `=H3:H8` |

If there's a possibility that you'll gather some more data, say, a few hundreds more, then use:

| Cell | Function |
| --- | --- |
| `I3` | `=IFS(G3:G1000="!null!", "", G3:G1000="", "", TRUE, G3:G1000)` |
| `J3` | `=IF(H3:H1000="", "", H3:H1000)` |

Comment: I was hoping I could do it without having to repeat the formula, but your solution does work.  The data isn't too much - only 3500 records since 21st February and it won't go over a rolling years worth of data.  If no one offers a non-repeating formula I'll go with your answer in the next day or so.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea to shorten the formula a bit - needed to sleep on it first though.  Wrap the `CHOOSE` function in `SUBSTITUTE` allows me to remove the !null! values, but then I can't format the dates as dates (they appear as their numerical value), so I wrapped the first `FILTERXML` in a `TEXT` function and it worked.  Having a text date is ok in this instance as I'm using it for a chart axis.  The final formula:  `=LET(xml,"<y><x>" & TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,Z4#,AA4#) & "</x></y>",x,"//x/a",y,"//x/b",SUBSTITUTE(CHOOSE({1,2},TEXT(FILTERXML(xml,x),"dd-mmm"),FILTERXML(xml,y)),"!null!",""))`